# Watson Conversation - NPM Start disconnects and shows error for invalid StatusCode

Tags: node.js, watson-conversation, watson

Everything is configured as per the instructions.
npm start enables the server but when I open the URL localhost:PORT it disconnects and shows error for Invalid StatusCode

```
C:\Temp\conversation-simple-master>npm start

> conversation-simple@0.1.1 start C:\Temp\conversation-simple-master
> node server.js

Server running on port: 81
_http_server.js:192
    throw new RangeError(`Invalid status code: ${statusCode}`);
    ^

RangeError: Invalid status code: 0
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:192:11)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:157:8)
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (_http_outgoing.js:573:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Temp\conversation-simple-master\node_modules\expr
ess\lib\response.js:204:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Temp\conversation-simple-master\node_modules\expr
ess\lib\response.js:249:15)
    at C:\Temp\conversation-simple-master\app.js:88:44
    at Request._callback (C:\Temp\conversation-simple-master\node_modules\watson
-developer-cloud\lib\requestwrapper.js:55:7)
    at self.callback (C:\Temp\conversation-simple-master\node_modules\watson-dev
eloper-cloud\node_modules\request\request.js:187:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! conversation-simple@0.1.1 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the conversation-simple@0.1.1 start script 'node server.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the conversation-simple package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node server.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs conversation-simple
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls conversation-simple
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Temp\conversation-simple-master\npm-debug.log
```

Need to know where is the issue or where can I check for the status code.

The website is showing the UI but is not showing the response.

Answer (score 0):

This was just due to the internet connectivity to the API call. While in local host it is working but when connecting to SSL it was having issue.

Just because of the Internet Authentication Client.